# How can I connect my SQLITE file to an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app in Visual Studio Code, but I am having trouble connecting it with an already existing SQLite database file.

I tried adding the database file by moving it into the mvc files but it didn't work

Comment: What is the error? Did you change the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working sample:
DBfile
[image]
program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UTsContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite("Filename=E:\\IISPUB\\UTs\\test2.db3"));
```

Context

```
    public class UTsContext : DbContext
    {
        public UTsContext (DbContextOptions<UTsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Entry> Entry { get; set; } = default!;
    }
```

Data Model

```
    public class Entry
    {
        public int ID {  get; set; }
        public DateTime RecordingTime { get; set; }
        public int Period { get; set; }
    }
```

A simple controller with get method

```
    [ApiController]
    public class EntriesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UTsContext _context;

        public EntriesController(UTsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Entry>>> GetEntry()
        {
            return await _context.Entry.ToListAsync();
        }
     }
```

test output
[image]